# How to use the derivative definition to prove the derivative of a straight horizontal line is zero

Tags: calculus, limits

If I have the function $f(x)=2$ then $f'(x)$ will obviously be equal to zero because at any x-value on the $f(x)$ function, the slope is zero. What I am trying to do is prove that $f'(x)=0$ using the derivative definition $f'(x)=\lim_{z\to x}\frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}$ where $(x,f(x))$ will be the point where our tangent line connects to $f(x)$ and where $(z,f(z))$ is our arbitrary point that will get infinitely closer to $(x,f(x))$. I keep getting an indeterminate answer and I can't find a way around this.

Comment: $\frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}=\frac {2-2}{z-x}=\frac 0{z-x}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any **fixed** $x\in\mathbb R$ you can think of $g(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}$ as a function defined on $\mathbb R-\{x\}$ with the property that $\lim_{z\to x}g(z)=f'(x)$ if the limit indeed exists.

In your case $g$ is evidently prescribed by $z\mapsto 0$, so the limit exists and equals $0$.

To get understanding for this observe that for every $\epsilon>0$ we can find a $\delta>0$ such that $0<|z-x|<\delta$ implies that $|g(z)-0|<\epsilon$. This because $g(z)=0$. In fact *any* $\delta>0$ will do.

This proves that $\lim_{z\to x}g(z)=0$.

Comment: One more question: In the limit definition I used, $(x,f(x))$ is the point where we are trying to find the slope. Since the function is also called $(f(x))$, I get confused because $f(x)$ therefore is both a coordinate and a function at the same time. How do I deal with this logically?

Comment: In this context $x$ must be looked at as *fixed*. Then consequently $f(x)$ is a fixed number (so no function). If you are bothered by confusion then you can use the notation $x_0$ (instead of $x$) in order to emphasize that. For a fixed $x_0$ we find the slope. This gives us $f'(x_0)$ as result. Then afterwards on base of the fact that this works for *every* fixed $x_0$ we draw the conclusion that for every $x$ the slope is $f'(x)$.

Comment: Why does everyone online seem to only use $x$ and therefore $f(x)$? It causes unnecessary confusion. For example, at 2:25 of the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ol-3uZfC-E , the $f(x)$ in the top question "Why isn't $f(x)=\lvert x\rvert$ differentiable at $x=0$?" is a function.

Comment: But then in the numerator of the fraction, that () means a fixed value. So now () takes on two different meanings. And then the guy, without any explanation why, ends up plugging in || at 2:25 which means he's plugging in a function for a fixed value which makes no sense. Every video I've watched I've spotted this problem it seems like a really poor pedagogical choice. I don't know why it's so widespread.

Answer (score 4):

$\lim_{z\to x} \frac 0 {z-x}=0$.

Comment: How do I know $lim_{z\to x} 0$ is $0$?

Comment: Write down the definition of limit.

Comment: You should always take limits after $z$ is removed from the expression. In this case $\lim_{z \to x} \frac{0}{z-x} = \lim_{z \to x} 0 = 0$.